# How to Pass One Row of a DataRow Array to a Method

Tags: vb.net

I am iterating through selected rows of a DataTable (based on certain criteria) using a DataRow array. When I try to pass one row of the array (using the index) to a Method that is expecting a DataRow, I get the error "Value of type 'System.Data.DataTable' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataRow'. Here is my code:

```
Dim InvRow() as DataRow = DS.Tables("Invs").Select([criteria])
For I As Integer = 0 to InvRow.Count - 1
    GetCommData(InvRow(I))
    'The above function "GetCommData" is expecting a DataRow, and this is
    'where I get the error.
Next
```

How do I send each selected row to the method?

Larry

Comment: I doubt that. If the method accepts `DataRow` it shouldn't complain because you are passing one. The error must be thrown somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't being generated by the first line?

Comment: I believe DS is a dataset object. If it is it must be the error in the first line.

Comment: what does `GetCommData` look like?  The error indicates it is written to accept a DataTable

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it must have been a typo. It is working fine now.